# how to add more than one foreign key in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

user model

```
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
```

topic model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many_comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

comment model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
```

I know that to add foreign key when i create a new post, we write( i'm using authlogic)

```
def create
  @topic = current_user.topics.build(params[:topic])
end
```

But what should i write to add more than one foreign key.For example when i add a comment,  what should i write ? Comment belongs to both User and Post. I don't want to use hidden fields. I need something in controller.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean - i dont understand what u want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're wondering how to create a `Comment` in the same way as `@topic = current_user.topics.build(params[:topic])` because Comment has two foreign keys, right?

When creating a `Comment`, you would post a request to some url like `/posts/16/comments`. So you can do something like this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id]  # or with permission checking
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
end
```

In the creating of a comment, the `user_id` should not be an arbitrary number from user inputs, and for the security issue, you'd better set `attr_protected` in your Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :user_id
end
```

Also, in the Post/Topic model too.